# how to get sbteclipse to work with unmanagedBase in Provided scope?

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

Snippet from my `build.sbt` file:

```
EclipseKeys.configurations := Set(Compile, Test, Provided)

unmanagedBase in Provided := new java.io.File("/path/to/external/libdir")
```

But when I run `sbt eclipse` I get this:

```
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] Undefined setting 'unmanagedSourceDirectories'!
[error] Undefined task 'externalDependencyClasspath' for 'myproject'!
```

Comment: I don't follow - how does `build.sbt` have any effect on `sbt eclipse`? What do you need `unmanagedBase in Provided` for?

Comment: Does it really matter why I need `unmanagedBase` in `Provided`? Don't see how that is relevant. Anyway - I need it because the jars there are part of a different application that I need - these jars will be located on the local filesystem when my app is deployed and I shouldn't actually include them in the deployable. As for `build.sbt` having an effect on `sbt eclipse` - of course it does - how else would eclipse get its build path generated?